# Why did Capcom cut the Championship off the Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition?

Tags: street-fighter-iv

I need to know why. SF used to provide a key-based championship mode, and it's not in Arcade Edition anymore.
I was told that it let cheat happen, but that could be solved without cutting this feature off.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Championship Mode DLC](http://www.capcom-unity.com/s-kill/blog/2009/04/16/sfivs_free_championship_mode_update_?num=5&pg=2) you are talking about is tagged as Downloadable Content (DLC).

[Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition (DLC)](http://thisismyjoystick.com/reviews/review-super-street-fighter-iv-arcade-edition-dlc/) is also tagged as DLC.

Capcom decided that they wanted two different experiences, so they released them as separate DLCs. Meaning that the features from the Championship edition are not available in the Arcade Edition.

Comment: Is it a DLC on PC? It costs 39.99 USD on Steam and you don't have to have SF4 to play the Arcade Edition...

Comment: I believe you get SF4 + Arcade Edition (DLC) as a bundle on the PC. Steam page is here : http://store.steampowered.com/app/45760/

Comment: I don't think so, they don't mention DLC anywhere and you cannot buy the DLC if you already own SF4. Anyway, I didn't know it was DLC on (at least) other platforms, so I think your answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Street Fighter IV, Super Street Fighter IV and Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition are different games. In consoles, Arcade Edition was released both as an expansion for Super Street Fighter IV and as a standalone game.

Answer (score 0):

In consoles, there was the [Super Tournament Mode DLC for Super Street Fighter IV](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Super-Tournament-Mode/00000000-0000-400c-80cf-0009434307fc), which enabled a "Tournament" option, that is similar to the "Championship" mode that was also released as DLC for Street Fighter IV. Looking at the screenshots for Super Street Fighter 4: Arcade edition on Steam, I can see the "Tournament" option there, but it looks like an XBox 360 screenshot.